# How to subset a large dataframe using many conditions for many variables in a simple way?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, multiple-columns

I have this dataframe (but let's imagine it with many columns/variables)

```
df = data.frame(x = c(0,0,0,1,0),
                y = c(1,1,1,0,0),
                z = c(1,1,0,0,1))
```

I want to subset this dataset based on the condition that (x=1) and (y=0 or z = 0 or etc..)

I am already familiar with the basic function that works for small datasets, but I want a function that works for bigger datasets. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `Reduce()`. The function `+` basically works as an `OR` operator since its result is `>0` if it contains any `TRUE` value.

Correspondingly, `*` would work as an `AND` since it only returns a value `>0` if all cases are `TRUE`.

```
df = data.frame(x = c(0,0,0,1,0),
                y = c(1,1,1,0,0),
                z = c(1,1,0,0,1))
nms <- names(df)

# take all variables except for `x`
nms_rel <- setdiff(nms, "x")
nms_rel
#> [1] "y" "z"

# filter all rows in which `x` is 1 AND any other variable is 0
df[df$x == 1 & Reduce(`+`, lapply(df[nms_rel], `==`, 0)) > 0, ]
#>   x y z
#> 4 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can filter a dataframe like this

```
subset(df, df$x == 1 & (df$y == 0 | df$z == 0))
```

Another option is to use `filter` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, x == 1, y == 0 | z == 0)
```